# Powershell - New-Mailcontact and Set-Contact

Tags: powershell

I have been trying to write a script so I can create New-Mailcontact using CSV file, if not already exist in ActiveDirectory.

If already exist in Active Directory then skip New-MailContact command  and  just run Set-MailContact.

Problem in the script: -

- It does create new Mailcontact  if not already exist in AD then  If the mailcontact does not exist as a member of the groups, add account to group. If it already exists, skip
  Also , new mail contact may be member 4 or 5 mail groups it will be add 4 mail groups called "1100-contact" like below. it will be add 5 mail groups called "1000-contact" like below.
- if already exist in Active Directory e.g I am saying as "contact2@contoso.com" like below. if its required because already may be wrong displayname in AD.
  it will update displayname based on CSV file again and then So already contact may be member of Group-Mail1 and Group-Mail2 it will add to groups if contact is not member to any of these Group-Mail5 and Group-Mail9 groups.

CSV :

```
Name,ExternalEmailAddress,group1,group2,group3,group4,group5
1000-contact,contact1@contoso.com,Group-Mail1,Group-Mail2,Group-Mail3,Group-Mail4,Group-Mail5
1100-contact,contact3@contoso.com,Group-Mail1,Group-Mail2,Group-Mail3,Group-Mail4
1200-contact,contact2@contoso.com,Group-Mail1,Group-Mail2,Group-Mail5,Group-Mail9
```

I have tried so far script :

```
Import-Csv C:\temp\ExternalContacts.csv|
foreach-object{
if (Get-MailContact -anr $_.ExternalEmailAddress) 
{
write-host $_.name 'is a duplicate entry!!!'

    Set-MailContact -Identity $_.ExternalEmailAddress -DisplayName $_.Name -ForceUpgrade -Confirm:$False
    Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity "$($_.group1)" -Member $_.ExternalEmailAddress
    Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity "$($_.group2)" -Member $_.ExternalEmailAddress
    Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity "$($_.group3)" -Member $_.ExternalEmailAddress
    Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity "$($_.group4)" -Member $_.ExternalEmailAddress
    Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity "$($_.group5)" -Member $_.ExternalEmailAddress
}       
else {


    New-MailContact -Name $_.Name -DisplayName $_.Name -ExternalEmailAddress $_.ExternalEmailAddress -OrganizationalUnit "OU=company_Contacts,OU=Contacts,DC=contoso,DC=com"

    Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity "$($_.group1)" -Member $_.ExternalEmailAddress
    Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity "$($_.group2)" -Member $_.ExternalEmailAddress
    Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity "$($_.group3)" -Member $_.ExternalEmailAddress
    Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity "$($_.group4)" -Member $_.ExternalEmailAddress
    Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity "$($_.group5)" -Member $_.ExternalEmailAddress

}
}
```

UPDATE :

I want to watch out for whitespace in your csv. So This will treat empty if group5 is empty. Am I correct ?

```
if ($_.group5) {
    Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $_.group5 -Member $ExternalEmailAddress
}
```

Comment: The CSV you show does not have columns for `FirstName` and `LastName`, so where do you get these from?

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question properly, the main issue is that some contacts need to be added to 4, while others need to be added to 5 distribution groups.

Untested, but this might work for you:

```
Import-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\ExternalContacts.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    # try and find the contact
    $contact = Get-MailContact -Filter "EmailAddress -eq '$($_.ExternalEmailAddress)'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($contact) {
        if ($_.Name -ne $contact.DisplayName) {
            Write-Host "Renaming contact $($contact.DisplayName) to $($_.Name)"
            Set-MailContact -Identity $_.ExternalEmailAddress -DisplayName $_.Name -ForceUpgrade -Confirm:$False
        }
        else {
            Write-Host "Contact $($_.Name) already exists"
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "Creating new contact $($_.Name)"
        $contactParams = @{
            Name                 = $_.Name
            DisplayName          = $_.Name
            ExternalEmailAddress = $_.ExternalEmailAddress
            OrganizationalUnit   = "OU=company_Contacts,OU=Contacts,DC=contoso,DC=com"
        }
        New-MailContact @contactParams
    }

    # get an array of groups this user should be a member of
    $groups  = ($_.PsObject.Properties.GetEnumerator() | Where-Object { $_.Name -like 'group*' -and ($null -ne $_.Value) }).Value
    # add the contact to the appropriate groups
    foreach ($group in $groups) {
        Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $group -Member $_.ExternalEmailAddress
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again. After `Renaming contact` action , I want to remove the mail contact from all Groups in the "Member Of" tab.  `Get-MailContact <name> | ForEach-Object { Get-ADObject $_.distinguishedname -Properties memberof } | Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $_ -MemberOf $_.memberof`    Am I correct ?  what do you recommended ?

Comment: @Arbelac But... That's a whole different question.. This one is about Adding contacts.